# Importar um projeto em angular dentro de outro projeto angular

Tags: angular, angular-routes, angular-6

Gostaria de saber se é possível eu importar um projeto inteiro em angular em outro projeto, exemplificando digamos que eu tenho um projeto financeiro e um projeto de estoque ambos prontos e funcionando mas em projetos separados, e agora eu gostaria de criar um novo projeto que vai importar esses dois projetos. Teria como ? Se sim qual a forma correta ?

Pode parecer estranho o que eu quero fazer, mas é por que temos um cliente que utiliza o projeto financeiro e outro cliente que utiliza o projeto de estoque e estamos fechando com um novo cliente que vai precisar de ambos os projetos. Então a minha ideia foi criar um novo projeto que vai importar esses dois já existentes, para facilitar manutenção e controle.

Answer (score 0):

Tem sim!
usando git [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Eu utilizo aqui e o projeto submodule pode ser importado em qualquer outro projeto.
Nele você vai conseguir, importar um projeto dentro do outro como se fosse um projeto do node_modules, mas o melhor você escolhe a pasta de referência que esse outro projeto vai ser importado.
E aí basta tu ultilizar com se fosse 1 projeto só.
Um exemplo é [imagem exemplo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUcte.png)

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).